# Login prompt after logout using Auth0 in ASP.NET Blazor Web Assembly client-side app

Tags: asp.net, blazor, auth0, blazor-client-side

I've just begun constructing a simple web assembly ASP.NET client-side web app with authentication powered by Auth0.

There are a few articles I've found walking you through the steps needed to do this, like this one: https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-blazor-tutorial-on-building-webapp-with-authentication/

Unfortunately since many of them were written it seems that Blazor client-side projects were ported from targeting .NET Core to .NET Standard and as a result it's not possible to install the NuGet Package needed: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`

Instead I found a tutorial from Microsoft that uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` which wraps some Javascript code needed to handle the authentication flow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I managed to get it working but when I log out and go to log in again the app automatically authenticates without taking me to the Auth0 login page. According to the [OpenID Connect specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) I need to send an optional `prompt` parameter set to `login` to force the showing of a login screen (what I would expect as a user after logging out).

The aforementioned `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` library has the ability to set this parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.prompt?view=aspnetcore-3.0

The WebAssembly library from what I can tell does not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.oidcprovideroptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Does anyone know a workaround?

My `Program.cs` is as follows:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ProviderOptions.Authority = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";
                options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
                options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ResponseType"];
                options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/";
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the Program.cs ? I guess you are not really logged out your app

Comment: @aguafrommars thanks, I've added it now.

Comment: IMO you should configure the provider options RedirectUri with an absolute URI like `options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5443/authentication/login-callback`. The PostLogoutRedirectUri should also be an absolute URI `https://localhost:5443/authentication/logout-callback` and you should set `ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes`. More, thoses URL should be configured as alowed redirect URI on your OIDC provider side

Comment: Hey @JamesMundy did you get anywhere with this? I'm coming up against the same thing myself now.

Comment: @BigTallJosh see the answer below that might help. I added a comment on the Auth0 forums but the guy that wrote the ASP.NET articles wasn't able to help right now as he hadn't looked into it yet. Sadly I went another route and put off using Blazer for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that I need to explicitly call the `logout` endpoint:
https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?javascript#logout

For now I have created a `Logout` component and added the logic inside - I hope there is a better way (e.g. configuring this as part of `AddOidcAuthentication` but I couldn't figure it out).

```cs
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager
@inject BaseAddress BaseAddress
@inject Auth0Config Auth0Config

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <button class=@($"{CssClass} btn btn-link") @onclick=BeginSignOut>Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    private async Task BeginSignOut()
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"{Auth0Config.Authority}/v2/logout?client_id={Auth0Config.ClientId}&returnTo={BaseAddress.Url}authentication/logout");
    }
}
```